# Prove that if $K_n$ has a decomposition of three pairwise isomorphic graphs, then $n\equiv$ $0$ or $1\pmod3 $

Tags: graph-theory

A decomposition of a graph G is a collection of subgraphs of G such that each edge of G  appears in exactly one of the subgraphs. For example, G and $\bar G$ form a decomposition of $K_n$ for $|V(G)|=n$.

Prove that if $K_n$ has a decomposition of three pairwise isomorphic graphs, then $n\equiv$ $0$ or $1\pmod3 $.

Start with the definition decomposition of graph :

$G$ = $H_1$ $\cup$ $H_2$, . . .,$\cup$ $H_k$

$V(G)$ = $V$ ($H_1$) $\cup$ $V$ ($H_2$), . . .,$\cup$ $V$ ($H_k$)

$E(G)$ = $E$ ($H_1$) $\cup$ $E$ ($H_2$), . . .,$\cup$ ($H_k$)

And $E$ ($H_i$) $\cap$ ($H_j$) = $\emptyset$

How do i prove that if $K_n$ has a decomposition of three pairwise isomorphic graphs, then $n\equiv$ $0$ or $1\pmod3 $ ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What is the number of edges in $K_n$?

Comment: @Angelo And the first rule of having three pairwise isomorphic graphs is that they have the same number of edges. Is that always possible?

Comment: @Angelo If there is a partition into three subgraphs with the same number of edges, then the number of edges must be divisible by $3$. If $n\equiv 2\pmod3$ then the number of edges is _not_ divisible by $3$.